Asynchronously generate and add POCO to List<T>
I'm executing a query that returns approximately 11,000 rows. Each one of these rows is mapped to a unique POCO that I wrote a lightweight ORM to handle creating, called ToCustomObject<T>. Right now, I have an already async method that gets the results of this query and puts them into a DataTable. I then loop through all of the rows and call ToCustomObject on them to generate my object, and then add it to a List<T>. The query itself only takes half a second, but the loop to generate all my POCOs takes multiple seconds.
public async Task<List<Foo>> GetFoosAsync()
{
    //empty list to populate and return
    List<Foo> foos = [];

    //example, this is not how the query actually executes, do not need assistance with this part
    string query = "select t.Field1, t.Field2 from Table";
    DataTable results = await customDbHandlerThatsNotRelevant.ExecuteQueryAsync(query);

    //async way to handle this?
    foreach (DataRow row in results.Rows)
        foos.Add(row.ToCustomObject<Foo>());

    return foos ;
}

I had thought about maybe using Task.WhenAll() to put all the generations into a task list and execute that way, but foos.Add() is not awaitable. I also looked into Parallel.ForEach(), but I'm not as familiar with that and from what I could tell, would not accomplish what I'm trying to do.
TL;DR: How can I make all occurrences of foos.Add(row.ToCustomObject<Foo>()); occur asynchronously?

List<T> is not thread-safe. The concurrent calls to the Add() will just break a list and crash the app. Can you consider some other (concurrent-friendly) collection?

Why is the ToCustomObject so slow? POCOs are supposed to be simple and lightweight. Are you running queries for each POCO?

Reflection, when not used very carefully, is extremely likely to perform very badly.  You need to make this implementation do it's work much more effectively, rather than trying to parallelize an extremely inefficient implementation.

Load "results" into a ConcurrentQueue. Use extra "workers" / Tasks to dequeue; process; and add to (not a List) a target concurrent collection: e.g. ConcurrentDictionary, Stack, Bag, or another Queue; then stage to an observable collection.

Well it greatly depends. Are you seeing performance bottleneck in that loop? If yes, then maybe it is worth parallelizing.
But generally, it is not meant to be executed asynchronously, as your method ToCustomObject is not async, so you would need to wrap each execution in Task, which is already overhead. Doing that for all item in a list may even downgrade your performance!
BUT, if you are seeing performance issues, I can suggest couple of ways:

wrapping ToCustomObject call in Task, creating Task for each item and awaiting them all at one
use Parallel.ForEach
if ToCustomObject is performing badly, maybe there's some synchornous code inside of it that can be done asynchoronously? Then you could make async version of ToCustomObject

Of course, you need to take care of your List beong accessed potentially from multiple threads, do you need to use some synchronization or threads safe collection.

Again, if it contains or can contain async operation, sure, make it async, but if it is synchronous, it does not make sense

It seems most of my performance issues were actually just waiting for the Swagger page to load all the results in. Testing with Postmans resulted in barely 1 second returns. However, Parallel.Foreach did shave a nice percentage off of even that, so I'll consider this accepted.

First of all I recommend using .NET Dapper, it does exactly what you need: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper
I am using this package multiple years now and I am a fan of it.
You can use Parallel.ForEach like so:
ConcurrentBag<Foo> foos = new ConcurrentBag<Foo>();

Parallel.ForEach(results.Rows, row =>
   {
        foos.Add(row.ToCustomObject<Foo>());
   }
);

When adding objects to a list in multiple threads you need to use a thread safe object, e.g. concurrent bag is thread safe.

There's absolutely no way that's not drowning in thread synchronization code compared to the actual work being done.

The database query is missing, that's correct. I wrote to recommend Dapper instead and linked it. Please explain why the loop should not work.
